# Read Excel files without using COM interop

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, 32bit-64bit, xls

I have a requirement to

> Read Excel files without using COM interop.

Found some possible ways to do the same.

I have used openxml method to read .XLSX files which will fail for .XLS files.
So planned to use oledb reading for .XLS files only.

Later i read some articles about the problems related to Jet database engine while reading Excel file, 
Jet library was not designed for 64-bit system and all.

I am developing application on 64bit computer and need to deploy on 32 bit servers.
Whether it will create any problems later?

And is it possible to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read .XLS files also?

```
private string GetConnectionString(string filepath)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // XLSX - Excel 2007, 2010, 2012, 2013
            props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
            props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 12.0 XML";            
            //props["Data Source"] ="h:\\A_TestOpenXML.xlsx";
            props["Data Source"] = "h:\\Book1.xls";
 //is it possible to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read .XLS files also?

            // XLS - Excel 2003 and Older
            //props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            //props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 8.0";
            //props["Data Source"] = "h:\\Book1.xls";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
            {
                sb.Append(prop.Key);
                sb.Append('=');
                sb.Append(prop.Value);
                sb.Append(';');
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

is it required to install office on server to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?

please help.

Comment: The ACE drivers are not supported in typical server environments. [MS Ace download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). See the details section on the MS download page.

Answer (score 2):

No, Office is not required on the machine if you're using the ACE driver to read the files. You just have to install the driver on the machines where the app will run.

You can use the ACE driver to read .xlsx files. <s>For .xls files you need to use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver</s> edit: OP confirms ACE driver v12 can read .xls files as well.

Another alternative for reading .xls files without having to install Excel on the machine, is to use [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), which can read/write .XLS (binary) files in .NET. I used it for several years and it works very well (and doesn't require you to install anything extra / is bundled with your app)

Comment: :For Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver to work need to compile x86 mode right? with above code(Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) i am able to read data from Book1.xls.

Comment: @Athul That's great, then. The last time I used the ACE driver to read .xls it didn't work (don't remember which version it was, but not v12, so you're good. Install the ACE driver on the machines your app will run, and celebrate! :)